# How can I add words to Android's User Dictionary using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

How can I add words to Android's User Dictionary using PhoneGap?

I'd like to enable a user to press a button and have the PhoneGap app add a list of words to the user's Android dictionary (such as key technical terms so they autocorrect).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A phonegap-build plugin would have to be used for this and as of this writing, one does not exist. You can view available phonegap-build plugins [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins).